# What is best: one resume or multiple versions?

Tags: resume, job-search

There seems to be a controversy as to how one should handle resumes:

One resume, all inclusive for all jobs (but maybe editing specific job titles)

Multiple resumes, each catering to a specific field

Unique resume for each and every job posting answered

Something in-between?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What advantages does tailoring a resume have over sending out generic resumes?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21377/what-advantages-does-tailoring-a-resume-have-over-sending-out-generic-resumes)

Comment: It is not a "controversy". They are simply opinions. Having one resume is less work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends..

- If you are in highschool it probably doesn't matter.
- If you are a senior professional with 20+ years of experience?
  Customizing it to be specific for whatever job you are applying to?
  Big benefit.

What matters is the person/system reviewing it. If you are applying through an automated system that will keyword scan your resume you have different needs than if you are sending it to a specific person in a company directly.

Likewise, if the jobs you are applying to are all very similar it probably matters less to have specific resumes. But if you are applying for different positions (for example, software engineer and project manager)? Then your resume should highlight your experiences *for those positions*.

Answer (score 2):

You need to target your resume/cv for each job you apply to, to make sure you are seen as relevant to both the hiring manager/hr and to the likely ats that will be scanning it when you send.

I keep a super resume and cv with everything,  then transfer/tweak/enhance on each role,  you need to spend the time, or you won't get an interview. As a hiring manager I can be the third or fourth to actually see your resume (if you count the ats,  more if an agency) so most will be filtered out long before.

Answer (score 1):

How much work do you want to do?

Resumes tailored to appeal to specific targets may help (assuming you don't introduce any errors in the editing process), but are a nontrivial hassle to maintain and create the risk of handing someone the wrong copy.... and the risk of leaving out something that they are more interested in than you expected.

Only you can decide whether the difference in your case will be significant enough to justify the effort, and whether you can reliably enough predict which direction to spin this.